# How do I check file name opened using Tkinter when name returned to main?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to check the filename of a file selected using Tkinter and tkFileDialog, but the program always crashes, even when I have the method preload a string to use and comment out the open file dialog.  Also, the open file dialog opens twice, first when I first run the program, and then again when I exit the first dialog, and when I try to close that one the program crashes.  I also tried using the entire directory as the string for the file name, but got the same result.  Here is the fairly simple code I'm using, any idea what is causing the problems?

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog




def bla():
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    if filename:
        print filename
        return filename
    else:
        print 'file not opened'




def main():


    if bla()=='somepic.bmp':
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'no'
main()
errmsg = 'Error!'
Button(text='File Open', command=bla).pack(fill='x')
```

Update:  Pictures of what happens, this is what appears immediately, whereas I just want one dialog box (the small one, which would open the larger one, also the button is missing)[image]

Update:  two dialog boxes opening when run is no longer problem, but 2 open if when you try to exit the first one:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
def callback():
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    if filename:
        print filename
        return filename
    else:
        print 'file not opened'
def main():
    mainloop()
    if callback().endswith('sen30.bmp'):
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'no'
Button(text='File Open', command=callback).pack(fill='x')

errmsg = 'Error!'
main()
```

I think it is stuck in mainloop and never reaches the if statement.  How do I get it out of mainloop?

Comment: `command=callback` leads to `NameError: name 'callback' is not defined` what did you expect?

Comment: also the filename returned (I believe) is always the absolute path, so I don't think it could ever be equal to just `'somepic.bmp'` but it could `.endswith` that.

Comment: Oh, lol, the command callback is a mistake on my part rofl.  A change I forgot to make.

Comment: Ok I fixed it.  Earlier I tried using absolute file path 'C:\directory\filename' but that didn't work either.

Comment: I tried running your program and the open file dialog only appears once. Please provide code that exhibits the problem you are describing.

Comment: How do I use .endswith?

Comment: I don't think it is crashing so much as it is... ending, you don't have an actual gui to call `mainloop` on so the program just ends.

Comment: and you would do `if bla().endswith('somepic.bmp')` but running `help(str.endswith)` would be more helpful in general... actually that would fail if the dialog is canceled and `bla()` returns None since None doesn't have an endswith method, so you would need to either `return filename` either way or make sure it isn't None before checking if it ends with something.

Comment: I'm going to post pictures of what is happening.

Comment: hint: you call `main()` immediately which calls `bla()` which opens the first dialog, this happens before the `Button` is created.  Also you are running the program in IDLE so it will work without necessarily using `mainloop` but it won't work in the standard interpreter.

Comment: Well that fixed my early opening file browser problem, now I have to figure out how to match filenames using some similar method to what you have with .endswith  .  Updating code to reflect new changes.

Comment: Ok, now it reopens that window if I exit the first one and if I press the button.